# How to autofill a function in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, autofill

I am trying to autofill and have found code for the problem however, Upon the autofill completing its action all of the cells simply produce the same result as from the original cell.

```
Sub Button2_Click()


Range("P2").Value = Application.Sum(Range(Cells(2, 18), Cells(2, 40)))

Range("P2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("P2:P5"), Type:=xlFillDefault

End Sub
```

Comment: `Application.Sum` returns the value. If you want to autofill, perhaps consider using a formula, or a loop.

Comment: FWIW instead of `Range("P2").Select` followed by `Selection.Something`, do `Range("P2").Something`. Don't `Select` stuff, you don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for, but if you're looking to use the `SUM` function, perhaps this one-liner:

```
Range("P2:P5").Formula = "=SUM(Q2:AN2)"
```

You can write the formula to the range in one go, no need to `AutoFill`.

If you just want the values, then add a second line to convert formulas to values:

```
Range("P2:P5").Value = Range("P2:P5").Value
```